# Is it possible to re-render a component after updating cache with React Query?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

In The root component, I received this data from the cache.

```
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const data = queryClient.getQueryData('prototypes');
```

In another component, after firing a function, I changed the data on cache (with optimistic update).
Although the data was changed in cache and shown in Devtools, new data in root component was not showing and component didn't refresh.

how can I re-render a component after changing cache?

Before, I used this way to get data in Ssr mode in Nextjs.

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ req }) => {
      const queryClient = new QueryClient();
      await queryClient.prefetchQuery('prototypes', getPrototypes);

      return {
        props: { dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient) },
      };
    }
);
```

In a child component, I used useQuery hook to get data.

```
  const { data: prototypes }: { data: FilterPrototypesByDateQuery } = useQuery(
    'prototypes',
    getPrototypes
  );
```

Although data was existed in cache, when this component was mounted, in network I saw that a new request to get prototypes was fired.

In other child component, when i liked a prototype, i used optimistic update to update cache. But i saw that a new request for prototypes was fired again.

```
 const { mutate: likePrototype } = useLikePrototypeMutation({
    onMutate: async (like) => {
      const previousPrototype: FilterPrototypesByDateQuery =
        queryClient.getQueryData('prototypes');

      const newState = produce(previousPrototype, (draft) => {
        const index = draft.prototype_getPrototypes.result.items.findIndex(
          (item) => item.id === prototypeId
        );
        if (index > -1) {
          draft.prototype_getPrototypes.result.items[index].isLiked = true;
        }
      });
      queryClient.setQueryData('prototypes', newState);
      return { previousPrototype };
    },
    onSettled: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries('prototypes');
    },
  });
```

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using a `useQuery`?

Comment: I edited the question and described why I couldn't use useQuery @JakubKotrs

Comment: well, if you never want the query to fire another request, you can set the cache and stale times to infinity. Is there any other reason to not use a query? If not, I will make an answer out of that.

Comment: I added { cacheTime: Infinity, staleTime: Infinity } to useQuery.  when i liked a prototype, i changed the cache with optimistic update, after that, the new query has been fired!! I want to prevent useQuery to fire a new query after I like a prototype @JakubKotrs

Comment: Sound like you also need to stop invalidating the query manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step when you want a query to not fetch new data ever again, is to set its cache and stale times to infinity. This makes RQ remember the data forever but also always return from cache.

```js
const { data: prototypes } = useQuery('prototypes', getPrototypes, {
  cacheTime: Infinity,
  staleTime: Infinity,
});
```

The next step is that you should not be manually invalidating the query. When you change it using `setQueryData`, it will be updated.

```js
const { mutate: likePrototype } = useLikePrototypeMutation({
  onMutate: async (like) => {
    // ...
    // this causes the component using that query to update
    queryClient.setQueryData('prototypes', newState);
    // ...
  },
  // no onSettled here
  // just rollback in onError
});
```